# Is USB/SD card a block device in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, hard-disk, usb-drive, block-device

In Linux kernel, are USBs, MMCs,SDcards considered as block device? If so, how does it realize if it is mounting/accessing a hard disk or another one? Because the physical organisation would be different, right?

Answer (score 1):

> In Linux kernel, are USBs, MMCs,SDcards considered as block device

The simple answer is yes.  USB drives will show up as the normal `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, etc.  MMC/SDcards may show up this way if the card reader is a USB-connected one (some internal card readers are actually USB under the hood) or show up as `/dev/mmcblk0`, `/dev/mmcblk1` (if you have more than one card reader) - partitions will be `/dev/mmcblk0p1`, `/dev/mmcblk0p2` etc.

You can use the `lsblk` command to get an easy quick view of all the block devices on your system at a given moment.

As far as telling the device type, Linux doesn't care what a block device actually is.  A block device is a block device to Linux and it's only  different in respect to size, whether it's physically read only or not, and whether it accepts extra commands such as `TRIM` for an SSD.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So it is all implemented by files in /block in the source code? Does that also mean if we disable BLOCK in configuration, it will disable all these memories as well?

Comment: You haven't been able to disable the block layer in `make menuconfig` (which controls options for building a Linux kernel) for a long time.  I think the only non-block-device file system is the virtual ones like `/proc` and `/sys`.  So you could only meaningfully have no block layer if you did something to mount `/proc` at boot (which I don't know if the kernel supports) and you had something there that would make an executable (like a custom device driver).  So really it's safe to assume you will always have block devices in a Linux system.

Comment: As mentioned in Kconfig available in /block, we disable block in case of some embedded systems. so how is that possible?